# How to compare 2 excel sheet in Blue prism

Tags: blueprism

I am new to blue prism. I was going through excel operation. Just came in my mind that if we want to compare given data in one excel sheet with obtained excel sheet data. How we are going to solve this issue.?

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. What exactly are you comparing? Is the data single-dimensional or multi-dimensional? What steps have you taken to solve the issue already?

Answer (score 0):

You may retrieve the data in from the two excel in the Collections first. Then you can compare the fields names, if they are similar you may proceed with the data comparison. following example is for fields comparison.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUllq.png)